# Как в базе MySQL найти пароль от админки вордпрес wordpress, и чтобы не в зашифрованном виде?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, хостинг

Как в базе MySQL найти пароль от админки вордпрес wordpress, и чтобы не в зашифрованном виде?
Спрашиваю для общего развития, вдруг забыл пароль от админки вордпресс wordpress, или забыл этот пароль заказчик услуг. Знаю в wp_users там есть, но в зашифрованном виде. Как его разшифровать? или лучшее решение будет поставить MD5 и прописать свой новый пароль, а старый пароль уже не реально отрыть, каким он был ?

Comment: забыл скриншот указать  
 https://prnt.sc/kiuybg

Comment: `UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass = MD5('newpassword') WHERE user_login = 'username';` и ничего никуда ставить не нужно. Расшифровать пароль нельзя - MD5 не реверсируется, а подбирать можно до морковкина заговенья... да и кому он, старый пароль, нужен-то?

Comment: Конечно же пароль в открытом виде не хранится. 
Расшифровать можно, но это совсем не вариант...
Проще и быстрее подставить новый.
Предварительно посмотреть на соли в wp-config

Comment: @Nilsan *Расшифровать можно* MD5 - это контрольная сумма, т.е. преобразование с потерями. Расшифровать его НЕЛЬЗЯ, только подобрать. Хотя бы потому, что теоретические количество паролей (ничем в общем не ограниченное) больше количества возможных MD5-сумм.

Answer (score 1):

Можешь перезаписать пароль https://generator-password.ru/encode-decode
Введи свой пароль, выбери MD5 и зашифрованный пароль замени в phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

> Как в базе MySQL найти пароль от админки вордпрес wordpress, и чтобы
>   не в зашифрованном виде?

Увидеть - никак . В базе хранится зашифрованный пароль на основе [blowfish](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish).
Поменять можно. ВП поймёт MD5, а после логина заменит хеш на другой.